# Realtivity and the measurement problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

If a quantum system is prepared and the eigenvalues are known but the experimenter gets in a spaceship and rockets off in a particular direction at relativistic speeds and then performs the measurement of the system from the spaceship with a telescope will there be any effects from relativity?

More specifically, as time will be dilated and length contracted, from the experimenter's frame of reference, would the differences between the eigenvalues (for position let us say) in the spectrum of the position operator hone in on one value in a way that is like collapse except caused by Lorentz transformations? For example, would the possible positions be constrained to a smaller subset as the experimenter goes faster?

Of course, if the experiment was performed by someone else and then the results transmitted there should not be any effects so the main question is if there could be effects on quantum measurement from Lorentz transformations. There might be an astrophysical example too, for example, it seems the extreme case would be a measurement of black hole properties that are themselves constrained by the no-hair theorem. So there might be something between this case and the one explained above.

Answer (score 1):

The whole premise of relativity is that the laws of physics are the same in any reference frame. If you are moving relative to me, and you observe me performing an experiment in my rest frame, you will see the same results as I do, except that they will appear to you to be transformed by the usual relativistic effects on distance and time. If, say, there was a set of allowed position states in my frame of reference, you would see exactly the same set of states, with their spacing suitably adjusted for length contraction.

Comment: Okay, so what happens as the adjustment for length contraction becomes on the order of the uncertainty in the experiment $\hbar / 2\Delta p$? Wouldn't the separate spectrum values merge into one contracted value?

Comment: No. The width of the uncertainty would reduce pro-rata with the spacings. The Lorentz transform is just that, a transformation of coordinates- it doesn't change the physics of the experiment.

Comment: But wouldn't it become impossible to determine the outcome as the system gets effectively contracted into an infinitesimal? How could you differentiate between different outcomes, would it become binary in a sense like it was measured or it wasn't without enough resolution to tell what was measured?

Comment: The whole scenario is entirely hypothetical/impossible. You can say that in principle small distances become harder to resolve if you are viewing them from a moving reference frame at near light speed, but in practice it's an impossibility anyway.

Comment: Unless you are trying to measure something that is spinning that fast like a neutron star or black hole. Is the no hair theorem (a classical theorem as I understand it) an example of all the quantum observables collapsing to non-measurablitity?

Comment: Good answer @Marco Ocram +1. For guitarphish, please do not add extra questions in comments. If you have additional questions please ask them as new questions. This is not a discussion forum.